# How to create video from frames using python?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I have about 10000 frames which I want convert into video.
These frames are 640x384 and video needs to be 25 fps.

I got these frames from another video of duration 20 mins (same res and fps) and consisting of 30000 frames.

Comment: The question is good (+1), but StackOverflow is not a we-write-your-code-platform...

Comment: Try [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) `ffmpeg -i *.jpg video.mp4`. Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Use [VideoWriter](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter)

You can define video codec type, frame rate and so on.